# Not able to send input argument values using subprocess Python Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I am running a main script on windows 10 that calls another script called audioplayer.py using the `subprocess` module in python.

I want to send some input arguments when calling the audioplayer.py. So I wrote the main script as follows:

The following is the main script:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "C:/Users/Jeff/Documents/audioplayer.py", "hey.wav"])
```

The following is my audioplayer.py:

```
"""OpenAL playback example."""
import os, sys, time
from openal.audio import SoundSink, SoundSource
from openal.loaders import load_wav_file

if len (sys.argv) < 2:
    print ("Usage: %s wavefile" % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
    print ("    Using an example wav file...")
    dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    fname = os.path.join(dirname, "default.wav")
else:
    fname = sys.argv[1]

sink = SoundSink()
sink.activate()

source = SoundSource(position=[10, 0, 0])
source.looping = True

data = load_wav_file(fname)
source.queue(data)

sink.play(source)

source.position = [source.position[0], source.position[1], source.position[2]]
sink.update()
time.sleep(2)

print("playing at %r" % source.position)
```

But I keep getting the following error even though the file does exist in the same directory as audioplayer.py

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hey.wav'
```

If I remove the `hey.wav` in the main script, it runs fine. It just doesn't seem to take any arguments.

Comment: `'hey.wav'` is a relative path, but it is not relative to the py file - it is relative to the current working directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
call(["python", "C:/Users/Jeff/Documents/audioplayer.py", "C:/Users/Jeff/Documents/hey.wav"])
```

When you run the last one, the dir is the same with the main.py instead of the audioplayer.py.